# How to find paths of images imported with gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files?

Tags: gatsby

Markdown pages with my images are being consumed and linked correctly by `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files`, but I need to build a JSON feed with the URLS to the images. So, I need to access the paths of the images after `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files` copies them in.

How do I query to find the paths to the images that `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files` uses to build the `<img/>` tags?

Comment: `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files` by default copy files to the root of your `public` folder, so unless you changed the setting, it should be there, i.e `public/myimage.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<img/>` tags can be found in the `htmlAst` property of the node.

Here is a graphql query to get the `htmlAst`:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark() {
    edges {
      node {
        htmlAst
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This function will descend into the html tree and find the `img` tags:

```
const imagesFromAst = htmlAst => {
  const findImageTags = node => {
    if (node.children) {
      const myTags = node.children.filter(propEq("tagName", "img"))
      const childrensTags = node.children.map(findImageTags)

      return [...myTags, ...flatten(childrensTags)]
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }

  return findImageTags(htmlAst)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files` only copies files to the `public` folder. Do you mean `gatsby-remark-images`? The latter automatically puts its images into the `public/static` folder. You can't access those links to the images then.